# Using an external merge tool does not work on SourceTree

Tags: xcode, git, macos

I am running `OS X.10`, `Xcode 7` and `SourceTree 2`.

When I select a conflicted file and `Launch an external merge tool`, there is a window that appears very briefly... and then *nothing happens*.

I tried (see [this help page](https://confluence.atlassian.com/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=267258218)) `sudo ln -s /Developer/usr/bin/opendiff /usr/bin/opendiff` but it did not work (I got the message `ln: /usr/bin/opendiff: File exists`).

What should I do?

### PS:

Here is a picture of the window that briefly appears.

[image]

### PPS:

Here are the SourceTree preferences:

[image]

Comment: Note that that help pages says it is for Xcode 4.2 and was written a few years ago - what version of Xcode do you have? Also anything that says chnage things in /usr/bin is a suspect source and now will not work in El Capitan. Also the error is because you already have /usr/bin/opendiff so the whole change is pointless

Comment: Have you run Xcode and agreed to the licence terms

Comment: I run Xcode 7 indeed! (but does this really make a difference?)

Comment: Have you installed command line tools? What does /usr/bin/opendiff show when run in the terminal

Comment: `2015-11-04 17:11:32.360 opendiff[10848:132187] too few arguments
2015-11-04 17:11:32.365 opendiff[10848:132187] usage: opendiff file1 file2 [-ancestor ancestorFile] [-merge mergeFile]`

Answer (score 3):

My problem was that I was running a previous version of Xcode and I hadn't set the command line tools.

Select the tools in Xcode's preferences -> locations:

[image]

Then run this command in terminal to verify:

```
git config --global -l
```

The git command will print out the path for the diff tool, amongst other config info. If it's not configured, it will output an error with something along the lines of the following:

```
xcrun: error: invalid active developer path (/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools),
```

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you are on latest version of SourceTree (Version 2.0.5.5 (2.0.5.5))

Try adding the following manually to your .gitconfig (or verify that SourceTree has put these exact lines)

```
[mergetool "sourcetree"]
    cmd = /Applications/SourceTree.app/Contents/Resources/opendiff-w.sh \"$LOCAL\" \"$REMOTE\" -ancestor \"$BASE\" -merge \"$MERGED\"
    trustExitCode = true
```

Or you could just enable 
"Allow  sourcetree to modify your global mercurial and git configuration files." in Preferences -> General tab

These lines will be automatically updated